# Is there a cantor set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}-\{0\}$ which intersects every ray from the origin?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $T$ denote the [Cantor ternary set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) on the real line with the usual topology. Any topological space $C$ homeomorphic to the Cantor ternary set is called a *Cantor set*.

The case $n=1$ is clear. For $n\ge 2$, **is there a cantor set in $\mathbf{\mathbb{R}^{n}-\{0\}}$ which intersect every ray from the origin?**

Comment: Is the Sierpinski carpet really homeomorphic to $T$? That sounds very unlikely, since $T$ is totally disconnected whereas the Sierpinski carpet contains a subset homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I edited the question.

Comment: The title is not a complete sentence, so does not contain any question. Nor does the body clearly state one. What are you asking?

Comment: Related: [Is there a Cantor set $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ so the graph of every continuous function $[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ intersects C?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/416982/15780)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For $n=2$, consider the function $f$ defined as: For $x\in T$, write $x$ as a ternary fraction with only the digits `0` and `2`. Replace every `2` with an `1`; $f(x)$ is then the value of the resulting digit sequence interpreted as a *binary* fraction.

Clearly $f$ is surjective $T\to [0,1]$. (It is the restriction of the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) to $T$)

Prove that the graph of $f$ -- that is, $\{(x,f(x))\mid x\in T\}$ -- is homeomorphic to $T$. Then distort this graph so it wraps around the origin.

---

Generalizing this to higher $n$ should just be a matter of splitting $f$ into $n-1$ functions that extract disjoint sequences of digit positions from $x$.

Alternatively, compose $f$ with a space-filling curve. (This option is probably easier to prove).

Comment: Very elegant, +1!

Answer (score 0):

The same idea works with no change: choose any surjective continuous map $p$ from the Cantor set $C$ to the unit sphere in $\mathbf{R}^n$, any injective continuous map $i$ from $C$ to the set of positive reals, and consider $j(x)=i(x)p(x)$ and $C'=j(C)$. Then $C'$ is a Cantor set intersecting every ray.

(How to construct $p$? a general result is that every nonempty metrizable compact set $X$ admits a continuous surjection from a Cantor set. One can be more explicit here of course since the sphere is a finite union of closed balls and each closed ball is homeomorphic to $[0,1]^{n-1}$.)